# Yii 2 не получается insert

Tags: yii2

пробую

```
    public function actionSell($id, $hero)
    {
        $table = 't_hero_has_equip';
        $id = 'hero_id';
        $has_equip_id = 'equip_id';
        $connection->createCommand()->insert($table, [
            $id => $hero,
            $has_equip_id => $id,
        ])->execute();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

получаю

```
PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function
 createCommand() on a non-object' 

in F:\OpenServer\domains\yii2basic\modules\shop\controllers\ShopController.php:107

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
#1 {main}
```

какой то неймспейс нужно подключить?

Comment: `$connection` не определен. Возможно вы имели ввиду `Yii::$app->db`?

Comment: вы правы. в доке http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html про это ни слова

Answer (score 1, accepted):

забыл

```
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;
```